# How to set up ices2 config file for 8-channel Zoom R16

Tags: alsa

I'm new to ices2 and icecast2, but did manage to set up a stream whereby I can hear myself in my earbuds. So, some basic success with the system. Now, the real goal:

We'd like to stream 8 different languages using the audio interface capabilities of a Zoom R16 Recorder. By doing `arecord --dump-hw-params hw1,0` on the R16, it returns:

```
Recording WAVE 'hw1,0' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
HW Params of device "default":
--------------------
ACCESS:  RW_INTERLEAVED
FORMAT:  U8 S16_LE S16_BE S24_LE S24_BE S32_LE S32_BE FLOAT_LE FLOAT_BE MU_LAW A_LAW S24_3LE S24_3BE
SUBFORMAT:  STD
SAMPLE_BITS: [8 32]
FRAME_BITS: [8 1024]
CHANNELS: [1 32]
RATE: [1 384000]
PERIOD_TIME: (2 4294967295)
PERIOD_SIZE: [1 1398102)
PERIOD_BYTES: [128 1398102)
PERIODS: [3 1024]
BUFFER_TIME: (7 4294967295]
BUFFER_SIZE: [3 4194304]
BUFFER_BYTES: [384 4194304]
TICK_TIME: ALL
--------------------
```

**Question 1:** What is the meaning of the numbers with spaces between them, such as `SAMPLE_BITS: [8 32]` ? Does that mean the sample bits can be 8, 16, or 32?

**Question 2:** How to resolve "EROR input-alsa/alsa_open_module Sample format not available: Invalid argument"

When I try to start ices2, it just quits, and the log says:

```
[2023-12-10  20:48:46] INFO ices-core/main IceS 2.0.3 started...
[2023-12-10  20:48:46] EROR input-alsa/alsa_open_module Sample format not available: Invalid argument
[2023-12-10  20:48:46] EROR input/input_loop Couldn't initialise input module "alsa"
[2023-12-10  20:48:46] INFO ices-core/main Shutdown complete
```

The config file I'm using for ices2 is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ices>

    <!-- run in background  -->                     <background>0</background>

    <!-- where logs go. -->                            <logpath>/var/log/ices2</logpath>
                                                       <logfile>ices.log</logfile> 
    <!-- size in kilobytes -->                         <logsize>2048</logsize>
    <!-- 1=error, 2=warn, 3=infoa ,4=debug -->        <loglevel>4</loglevel>
    <!-- logfile is ignored if this is set to 1 --> <consolelog>0</consolelog>

    <!-- optional filename to write process id to -->  <pidfile>/var/log/ices2/ices.pid</pidfile> 

    <stream>
        <!-- metadata used for stream listing -->
        <metadata>
            <name>8 Languages</name>
            <genre>Dharma Teaching</genre>
            <description>Translation of 2024 International Spring Festival</description>
            <url>http://localhost/</url>
        </metadata>

        <!--    Input module.

            This example uses the 'alsa' module. It takes input from the
            ALSA audio device (e.g. line-in), and processes it for live
            encoding.  -->
        <input>
            <module>alsa</module>
            <param name="rate">48000</param>
            <param name="channels">8</param>
            <param name="device">hw:1,0</param>
            <param name="periods">2</param>
            <!-- Read metadata (from stdin by default, or -->
            <!-- filename defined below (if the latter, only on SIGUSR1) -->
            <param name="metadata">1</param>
            <param name="metadatafilename">testES</param>
        </input>

        <!--    Stream instance.

            You may have one or more instances here.  This allows you to
            send the same input data to one or more servers (or to different
            mountpoints on the same server). Each of them can have different
            parameters. This is primarily useful for a) relaying to multiple
            independent servers, and b) encoding/reencoding to multiple
            bitrates.

            If one instance fails (for example, the associated server goes
            down, etc), the others will continue to function correctly.
            This example defines a single instance doing live encoding at
            low bitrate.  -->

        <instance>
            <!--    Server details.

                You define hostname and port for the server here, along
                with the source password and mountpoint.  -->

            <hostname>localhost</hostname>
            <port>8000</port>
            <password>hackme</password>
            <mount>/spanish.ogg</mount>
            <yp>1</yp>   <!-- allow stream to be advertised on YP, default 0 -->

            <!--    Live encoding/reencoding:

                channels and samplerate currently MUST match the channels
                and samplerate given in the parameters to the alsa input
                module above or the remsaple/downmix section below.  -->

            <encode>  
                <quality>0</quality>
                <samplerate>24000</samplerate>
                <channels>8</channels>
            </encode>

            <!-- stereo->mono downmixing, enabled by setting this to 1 -->
            <downmix>0</downmix>

            <!-- resampling.
            
                Set to the frequency (in Hz) you wish to resample to, -->
             
            <resample>
                <in-rate>48000</in-rate>
                <out-rate>24000</out-rate>
            </resample>
        </instance>

    </stream>
</ices>
```

But overall, what I'd like to know is:

**Question 3:** What needs to go into the config file so that channel 1 of the recorder can be streamed as Spanish, channel 2 as French, channel 3 as German, ... channel 8.  I'm assuming I actually need 8 different config files and run 8 instances of ices2, but how to select the right channel?

Edit: I can say also that this works to record an 8-channel wav file:

```
arecord -D hw:1,0 -f S32_LE -r 48000 -c 8 testr16.wav
```

Comment: Beginning to answer my own question...by changing `hw:1,0` to `plughw:1,0`, the error in question #2 goes away, and icecast2 does stream the device, but it seems that all the channels are downmixed into one.  So, how to select any one of the channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it working, with these key areas:

- Split the streams at the level of ALSA in `~/.asoundrc`
  -- Use `dsnoop` to split
  -- All streams from one hardware device need to use the same ipc_key.
- In the ices2 config files
  -- The device is `plug:{name from .asoundrc}`
  -- Get the channels right. I had left it set for 8 channels, even though alsa was now providing a single-channel pcm, that resulted in screechy noises beings streamed!
- In `/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml` had to increase `<sources>8</sources>`

Here is the final `~/.asoundrc`. Note that because all the dsnoop channels come from the same hardware device, they need to have the *same* ipc_key. Otherwise, once you start recording from one channel, the rest report as *Device is busy*.

```
pcm_slave.r16 { pcm "hw:1,0"; rate 48000; channels 8 }
pcm.ch1 { type dsnoop; ipc_key 3700; slave r16; bindings.0 0; }
pcm.ch2 { type dsnoop; ipc_key 3700; slave r16; bindings.0 1; }
pcm.ch3 { type dsnoop; ipc_key 3700; slave r16; bindings.0 2; }
pcm.ch4 { type dsnoop; ipc_key 3700; slave r16; bindings.0 3; }
pcm.ch5 { type dsnoop; ipc_key 3700; slave r16; bindings.0 4; }
pcm.ch6 { type dsnoop; ipc_key 3700; slave r16; bindings.0 5; }
pcm.ch7 { type dsnoop; ipc_key 3700; slave r16; bindings.0 6; }
pcm.ch8 { type dsnoop; ipc_key 3700; slave r16; bindings.0 7; }
```

Don't forget to restart ALSA: `sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils restart`

Then I made 8 separate ices2 config files,

```
ices-alsa-r16.1.xml 
ices-alsa-r16.2.xml 
...
ices-alsa-r16.8.xml
```

And here is the config file. The three things that change are the device, mount, and pid:

device: `plug:ch1` to `plug:ch8`
mount: `ch1.ogg` to `ch8.ogg`
PID file: `r16.1.pid` to `r16.8.pid`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ices>

    <!-- run in background  -->                     
    <background>1</background>
    <logpath>/var/log/ices2</logpath>
    <logfile>ices.log</logfile> 
    <logsize>2048</logsize>
    <loglevel>4</loglevel>
    <consolelog>0</consolelog>
    <pidfile>/var/log/ices2/r16.8.pid</pidfile> 

    <stream>
        <metadata>
            <name>8 Languages</name>
            <genre>Dharma Teaching</genre>
            <description>Translation of 2024 International Spring Festival</description>
            <url>http://localhost/</url>
        </metadata>

        <input>
            <module>alsa</module>
            <param name="rate">48000</param>
            <param name="channels">1</param>
            <param name="device">plug:ch8</param>
            <param name="periods">3</param>
            <param name="buffer-time">500</param>
        </input>

        <instance>
            <hostname>localhost</hostname>
            <port>8000</port>
            <password>hackme</password>
            <mount>/ch8.ogg</mount>

            <encode>  
                <quality>0</quality>
                <samplerate>24000</samplerate>
                <channels>1</channels>
            </encode>
             
            <resample>
                <in-rate>48000</in-rate>
                <out-rate>24000</out-rate>
            </resample>
        </instance>

    </stream>
</ices>
```

Some good info here:
https://alsa.opensrc.org/Asoundrc
https://bootlin.com/blog/audio-multi-channel-routing-and-mixing-using-alsalib/